# How to load only one entry of a cell from a .mat file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, import

I have a 1 by 5 cell containing 5 very large matrices. Instead of loading the whole cell, which eats up most of my memory, how can I load just the one matrix I want?

So something like

```
M2 = load('Cellmat{2}');
```

should define `M2` to be the second matrix in the cell `Cellmat`, which has previously been saved to the directory by `save('Cellmat','Cellmat');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this would be to use [`matfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) to read the file since that allows you to only read [parts of variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html#bt19yqz-1). It also assumes that the file was intitially saved in the `7.3` format

> `matfile` only supports efficient partial loading and saving for MAT-files in Version 7.3 format. If you index into a variable in a Version 7 (the current default) or earlier MAT-file, MATLAB® warns and temporarily loads the entire contents of the variable.

So to save your data initially you'll want to specify the `-7.3` flag.

```
save('Cellmat.mat', 'Cellmat', '-v7.3')
```

Then you can use `matfile` to load *just* the elements that you want from `Cellmat`. Note that you have to access it using `()` indexing (which will yield a cell which we can then index into to get `M2`) and you have to specify the row and column subscripts when indexing into `Cellmat`.

```
mat = matfile('Cellmat.mat');

% A little workaround because you can't use {} indexing on matfile objects
tmp = mat.Cellmat(1, 2);
M2 = tmp{1};
```

The "old school" alternative would be to break your cell array up into separate variables and save/load just those variables

```
thing = Cellmat{1};
other_thing = Cellmat{2};

save('Cellmat.mat', 'thing', 'other_thing');

% Only load in one variable
M2 = load('Cellmat.mat', 'other_thing');
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It seems weird that Matlab doesn't have a standard way of doing this..

Comment: @Lovsovs This *is* the standard way of doing this. Before `matfile` we had to do it with multiple variables as I've shown in my last edit

Comment: I'm sure it is the best way of doing it, that was not what I meant.. I just think it is still kind of a "hacky" way of doing it (with v7.3 and tmp and all that jazz), i.e., IMO Matlab should have a more intuitive way of achieving the same. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Lovsovs Well, so the 7.3 saves it as a HDF5 file which is a more modular datatype that allows better random access to data. And the `()` indexing (resulting in the `tmp`) is an artifact of how it's stored. To see more about the internals of these files, you can check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526334/matlab-matfile-increases-in-size-when-overwriting-cell-data/41526862#41526862)