# MatFile objects only support '()' indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

What does the following error message mean?

> MatFile objects only support '()' indexing

And is this limitation for all versions of .mat files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this error is really specific to `v7.3` .mat files since those are required in order to allow `matfile` to access only parts of the data  without loading the entire variable into memory

> Efficient partial loading and saving requires Version 7.3 MAT-files. To create a Version 7.3 MAT-file, call the save function with the '-v7.3' option

If you have a non-`v7.3` .mat file, then you will need to load the entire variable into memory *before* indexing into it.

The error message that you are receiving is because only indexing with smooth parentheses (`()`) is supported. Additionally, it is not possible to index into the following types

- Variables of tables
- Cells of cell arrays
- Fields of structure arrays
- User-defined classes
- Sparse arrays

We can illustrate this with a cell array as an example

```
% Create a cell array
A = {1, 2, 3};

% Save the cell array as a v7.3 .mat file so that it supports indexing
save('A.mat', 'A', '-v7.3')

% Create a matfile object
m = matfile('A.mat');

% Try indexing with {}
first_value = m.A{1}
```

> MatFile objects only support '()' indexing

However, if we use `()` indexing (as the error message states) this works, *but* `()` indexing into a cell array yields a *new* cell array so you'll need to treat it like such. See more information on indexing into cell arrays in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

```
first_value = m.A(1);

iscell(first_value)
%   1

size(first_value)
%   1   1

actual_value = m.A{1};
```

The *reason* for this likely has to do with how the complex datatypes are stored within a `v7.3` .mat file (more info in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526334/matlab-matfile-increases-in-size-when-overwriting-cell-data/41526862#41526862)).